# Brutal truncation of indecomposable complexes

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, chain-complexes

Let $P^{\bullet} = (P^i, d^i)_{i\leq 0}$ be an **indecomposable** object in category of complexes bounded above, where each $P_i$ is a finitely generated projective module over an finite dimensional algebra. Denote by $\tau^{\geq -n} (P^{\bullet})$ the brutal truncation of $P^{\bullet}$, $n \geq 1$, i.e.,
$$
\tau^{\geq -n} (P^{\bullet}) = \cdots \to 0 \to P^{-n} \to \cdots \to P^{-1} \to P^{0} \to 0 \to \cdots
$$

Is it **indecomposable** $\tau^{\geq -n} (P^{\bullet})$ for all $n \geq 1$?

Thanks!

**Edit**:

– Suppose $P^{\bullet}$ is **unbounded below**, i.e., $P^{\bullet} \in \mathcal{C}^{-}(\text{proj}-A) \setminus \mathcal{C}^{b}(\text{proj}-A)$.

– Suppose $P^0 \neq 0$, in order to fix notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Let $k$ be a field, and let $A = k[x,y]/(x^2, y^2, xy, yx)$.  Then the morphism $A \to A\oplus A$ sending $1$ to $(x,y)$ gives an indecomposable complex
$$P^\bullet: \ldots \to 0 \to A\to A\oplus A\to 0 \to \ldots $$
If you put $A\oplus A$ in degree $-1$, then $\tau^{\geq -1}(P^\bullet)$ is not indecomposable.  Notice that the image of the map described above lies in the radical of $A\oplus A$.

---

**Edit:** An example which is unbounded below can be obtained using the same algebra $A$.  Take the following complex:
$$ Q^\bullet : \ldots \longrightarrow A\oplus A \stackrel{\begin{pmatrix}y & 0 \\ x & 0\end{pmatrix}}{\longrightarrow} A\oplus A \stackrel{\begin{pmatrix}y & 0 \\ x & 0\end{pmatrix}}{\longrightarrow} A\oplus A \stackrel{\begin{pmatrix}x & 0 \end{pmatrix}}{\longrightarrow} A \longrightarrow 0 \longrightarrow \ldots,$$
where $A$ is in degree $0$. Then $Q^\bullet$ is indecomposable, but $\tau^{\geq -n}(Q^\bullet)$ has a direct summand given by the complex with $A$ concentrated in degree $-n$, so it is not indecomposable.

Comment: Thank you, @Pierre-Guy. I understand your example, but that was not what I thought when I wrote my question. For $\tau^{\geq -n} P^{\bullet}$ with $n\geq 1$ wanted to say:
$$
\tau^{\geq -1} P^{\bullet} = \cdots \to 0 \to P^{-1} \to P^0 \to 0 \to \cdots
$$

$$
\tau^{\geq -2} P^{\bullet} = \cdots \to 0 \to P^{-2} \to P^{-1} \to P^0 \to 0 \to \cdots
$$
$$
(\cdots)
$$
with $P^0 \neq 0 \neq P^{-1}$. Do you understand me?

Comment: @Chico I'm not sure I'm following you.  Is the fact that $P_0 = 0$ the only problem with my example, or am I missing more conditions?

Comment: thank you for the attention and sorry the poor english. See I **edited** my question.

Comment: using your example: Let us denote by **x** and **y** the endomorphisms of $A$ given by the multiplications of $x$ and $y$ respectively. Let 
$$
P^{\bullet}: \cdots \to A \to A \to A \to A \to 0 \to \cdots
$$
where $d^i =$ **x** when $i$ is **odd** integer and $d =$ **y** when $i$ is **even** integer. So $P^{\bullet}$ is indecomposable object in $\mathcal{C}^{-}$ and for each $n\geq 1$, $\tau^{\geq -n} P^{\bullet}$ is indecomposable object in $\mathcal{C}^{b}$.  Notice that the image of the maps **x** and **y** lies in the radical of $A$.

Comment: @Chico I've edited my answer to include an example which is not bounded below.

Comment: I checked it for $n=1$, but not for $n>1$. Unless I have some wrong calculation. I'll try to disprove for $n>1$. 

**Question**: How do you prove that $Q^{\bullet}$ is indecomposable? Showing that End$(Q^{\bullet})$ is local?

Thank you!

Comment: using the diagram
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10286131/diagrama.png we have $(xf \; yf) = (0 \; 0)$, $(hx + ky \; 0) = (0 \; 0)$ and $hf + kg = 1$. Thus $f\in \text{rad}(A)$, $hx = -ky$ and so $h,k \in \text{rad}(A)$. Therefore $kg = 1$, contradiction.

Comment: For any $n$, the second copy of $A$ in degree $-n$ is in the kernel of the differential; this copy is thus a direct factor of the complex.  As to why it is indecomposable, one can show that the only idempotents in its endomorphism ring are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: In my last comment, I meant the second copy of $A$ in degree $-n$ in $\tau^{\geq -n}(Q^\bullet)$.

Comment: Yes, of course!